# What is the exhaustive list of all "android.intent.action" actions available in the Android SDK?

Tags: android, android-intent, action

Hi fellows,

I'd like to know if there is some exhaustive reference of all Intent actions defined in the standard Android SDK ? I'm thinking of the full "android.intent.action.someaction" names, not the restricted list of conveniently aliased actions defined in the Intent class, e.g Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED, etc...

For those who believe all Intent actions are aliased in the Intent class (I was one of them until very recently) I have at least one action which is not : android.intent.action.HDMI_PLUG (defined in media/java/android/media/AudioService.java) and I believe there are many others.

But I could not find some exhaustive list in the Android Reference, so maybe if you can direct me to some place I can find it ?

Thanks !

--- UPDATE 23/01/2012 15h36 ---

Thanks to CommonsWare for mentioning HDMI_PLUG is not at all part of the Android SDk... it was a bad example, but still, there are intents that are not defined in Intent.java, such as TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED.

Comment: What about [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Hey I think I answered my own question :)

In my Android SDK directory, under /platforms/android-x/data (x being the API level) I've found several very interesting files:

- activity_actions.txt
- broadcast_actions.txt
- categories.txt
- features.txt
- widgets.txt

Turns out the first two contain plenty of raw Intents, including ones that are not defined in Intent.java !

I'm not quite sure what theses lists are here for, I'd just like to be sure they are exhaustive for their API level... (even if I don't see why they wouldn't be)

Comment: you should only use intents exported by sdk, otherwise you will not be sure if they will be supported in the future

Comment: https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/febed84a3a3cb7c2cb80d580d79c31e22e9643a5/sdk/platforms/android-23/data

Answer (score 7):

If there is any exhaustive list, it'd be here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html starting at "Standard Activity Actions".

Comment: No reference to android.intent.action.HDMI_PLUG --> not what I'm looking for ;)

Comment: No reference to android.intent.action.BADGE_COUNT also!

Answer (score 6):

> I'd like to know if there is some exhaustive reference of all Intent actions defined in the standard Android SDK ?

No.

> For those who believe all Intent actions are aliased in the Intent class (I was one of them until very recently) I have at least one action which is not : android.intent.action.HDMI_PLUG (defined in media/java/android/media/AudioService.java) and I believe there are many others.

If it is not in the SDK, there is no guarantee that it will exist on any given version of Android (past/present/future) or on any given device (given manufacturers' ability to change non-SDK elements). Specifically in this case, there is no `AudioService` in the Android SDK and there is no `HDMI_PLUG` action in the Android SDK.

Comment: Hi again CommonsWare, well you're actually right, the HDMI_PLUG Intent is actually not part of the SDK, it's not even part of any of the standard Android APIs... It was actually a really bad example, sorry about that, but still, what about the TelphonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED ? This one is part of the Android SDK I'm pretty sure this time ! :) Yet it's not in the Intent class...

Comment: @Wouzz: This is why I answered "no" to your first question.

Answer (score 0):

No, at least I have not found an exhaustive list and have been looking for one. I was looking for all of the NFC related Intents (e.g. ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED, ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED, ...). 
  It seems like the developer.android.com documentation is all piece-meal. What I mean is that there is hardly any 'definitive' sections on anything. A little bit frustrating. (But that's just my opinion).