# List of intents for major activities in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there a list anywhere available that lists all of the major activities that can be called with intents for things like e-mail, camera, system functions, etc.? I wasn't able to find such a list on Google's Android developer site. I'm curious how some developers here in SO are able to come up with the Intents and their parameters when they aren't even published by Google. Or are Google employees publishing them here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html) it is. Straight from Google Developer guide.

**Update** : [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) are some more intents , again from developer guide. It has detailed explanation as to what does each `Intent` do.

Comment: That list has hardly anything in it. It even states "Note that this list is not comprehensive". No shit. There are probably a hundred more Intents out there.

Comment: @Droider: Actually, that list is not "comprehensive", though it does cover a lot of ground. Android `Intent` actions are scattered throughout the SDK (e.g., some are on `android.provider.Settings`). There is no single repository within the documentation.

Comment: The weird thing is that I always end up using SO to find how intents are implemented almost never from the docs simply because, as you say, they are scattered everywhere.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971160/what-is-the-exhaustive-list-of-all-android-intent-action-actions-available-in like told in this questions, there is a big list in your sdk folder.